# Appears a Dual Interface Network Card is assigning two addresses to the same port rather that one per port

Tags: debian, ethernet

I have  an Intel dual port 10GB NIC.
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-7-amd64

```
  01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)
```

One port is configured with a static IP, 1000 Mb/s connected to a Cisco switch and works fine.
(I've removed the mac info)

```
3: enp1s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
    inet 192.168.69.224/24 brd 192.168.69.255 scope global enp1s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'm working on the other as a 10000Mb/s though a different switch, but in the same network.
This is to take advantage of the higher speed, on which other 10000Mb/s devices will be installed.
The 10Gb/s switch HAS NOT BEEN CONNECTED to the LAN as of yet.

It too has a static IP that I set via command line command.

```
ip addr add 192.168.69.6/24 dev enp1s0f1


4: enp1s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 192.168.69.6/24 scope global enp1s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here's the unexpected part.
I can ping the IP address of the 10Gb/s from my laptop on the production network (see below).
I have seen this kind of situation with other Debian systems using two ports/multiple connections but never looked into it due to not enough time, and as long as bother ports are connected everything works.  Maybe I'm mistaken, and only one port of the other Debian compuyers actually work.

In this case, because the 10 Gb/s port is being connected with a different speed and switch, it is an issue.

```
Pinging 192.168.69.6 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.69.6: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.69.6: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.69.6: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.69.6: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.69.6:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here's the unexpected part. I can ping the IP address of the 10Gb/s from my laptop on the production network (see below).

That's not unexpected: Both IP addresses are in the same subnet, so any ARP request for `192.168.69.224` in "production network" behind `enp1s0f1` will get broadcast to this address, and the Linux kernel will answer this for **any** local IP addresses.

If you really want to keep the networks behind both ports separate, you need different subnet ranges for them (but you didn't describe the topology of the rest of your network). If you put them into the same subnet, that's the same as stating your intent "I **want** both addresses to be reached from this subnet, through whatever switch gets their first".

Comment: dirkt,

Yep, I didn't think of the ARP.  
I can create another subnet/VLAN on the same switch - which in my case, seems to be a reasonable solution.

Thanks!